# threading: join() never returns

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to create multiple threads, add them to a list, go through that list and `join` each one like this:

```
threads = []
for i in range(0, 4):
    new_thread = threading.Thread(target=Runnable())
    new_thread.start()
    threads.append(new_thread)
for thread in threads:
    print("in thread")
    print(thread)
    thread.join()
    print("after join")
```

It will print "In thread" and the thread, but it never prints "after join" and because of that all of my code after does not run. `Runnable()` is a function I created, which also prints what it should so I'm not sure if that code has anything to do with it.

Comment: Does your Runnable() function ever return?

Comment: No. It does some stuff, then adds a record to a queue, which I then use later. Its not meant to return anything

Comment: Consider adding the `runnable` code. Does the `runnable` ever end?

Comment: Does `Runnable` create an object to run, or does it just start doing stuff? (The whole `Runnable` thing sounds like an unnecessarily Java design.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `Runnable` as you create each `Thread` instance, so the thread's `target` function is whatever it returns (possibly `None`). Try using:

```
new_thread = threading.Thread(target=Runnable)
```

Which has `target=Runnable` instead of `target=Runnable()`.